# How to get the blue range circle in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

Right now my Android app uses an overlay to place a pin down from drawable. I want a range in there too just like Google maps has when it is locking on to your position. How do I get that? Do I have to do an overlay, or is it part of maps?

BTW I am not drawing my loction, but a specific geopoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah in the overlay class, in function

```
draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)
```

You can use the canvas.[drawCirlce](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)() 
Of course is a bit more complicated than that, you will have to play around with the api's

Use

```
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();        
Point point = new Point();
projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);
```

to map your geoPoint to the projection on the MapView.

Comment: Could I create a new drawable circle or do I have to use Canvas

Comment: [Yeah you can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825358/strange-drawing-artefact-using-custom-drawable-with-mapview)